# Using reserved words in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, hadoop2, hive-configuration

I'm migrating data to Hive 1.2, and I realized that, by default, I'm no longer allowed to use reserved words as column names. If you want to use reserved words, you need to explicitly set the below setting:

```
hive.support.sql11.reserved.keywords=false
```

My question is, does changing this default value result in any unexpected issues? Are there any problems I should be aware of before changing it?

By the way, this change is documented in this ticket: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-6617

Comment: You can still use whatever string literal you want, as long as you **quote** the column name every time with **back-quotes** *(and you avoid punctuation)* => `create table DUH (\`user\` string, \`Look ma no hands\` string)`

Comment: Yeah I saw that solution too, but I was hoping to be able to keep the table exactly the same as it was in previous versions. I've always found quoted column names to be confusing.

Answer (score 6):

This configuration property `hive.support.sql11.reserved.keywords` was added in Hive 1.2.0 with [HIVE-6617](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-6617) and is removed in Hive 2.3.0 with [HIVE-14872](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-14872)

It was removed to simplify parser logic and  reduce the size of generated parser code.
Please read the description in the [HIVE-14872](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-14872) for more details.

Taking this into account, rewrite your code using **quoted identifiers** (using backticks) OR rename identifiers the sooner the better.

Comment: What is the new settings for hive.support.sql11.reserved.keywords in HIVE 3 version, is it the same or there is any other settings

Comment: @SanthoshChakka This setting is removed. Use backticks or rename.